# Galactic Registry Bitizens?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I got my first Galactic Registry character. Besalisk. I saw another user asking about them a few days ago, but at the time, they seemed to be locked for everyone. Has anyone else seen any or know what they do?

Answer (score 1):

Just a way for them to add new species to the game. They'll probably release a few each week with the Monday updates. So far Besalisks are the only ones you can get.

Comment: My Besalisks had been moved to a separate category called Set 14 after the latest update. Those in the Galactic Series can be unlocked through the Salvage Droid event that has been going on since.